# When does `modify` copy the vector?

Tags: performance, haskell, vector, functional-programming, immutability

From https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.0.1/docs/Data-Vector.html#v:modify

> Apply a destructive operation to a vector. The operation will be performed in place if it is safe to do so and will modify a copy of the vector otherwise.

This sounds like it can have drastically different performance characteristics depending on whether it is deemed "safe" to modify the vector in place. This motivates the questions...

When will the modify be performed in place, and when will the vector be copied? Is there some way to ensure, by use of the type-system for example, that it *will* be modified in place?

Comment: Probably if *after* the operation is performed, no object is pointing to the original vectoy anymore.

Comment: Looking at the source code, I can't see how it would ever not copy the vector; It seems to always call `basicUnsafeCopy`, which copies the vector.

Comment: Pretty sure there is no way to guarantee any such thing through the standard Haskell type system; it's actually one of the main goals of GHC's [linear types](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/LinearTypes) research to make that possible.

Comment: Perhaps that's a (confusing) way to indicate that the monadic modifier-function argument `forall s. MVector s a -> ST s ()` can write on the vector many times without vector copies being made after the initial one. That is: the vector is copied only once, even if the modifier-function reads/writes a large number of times.

Comment: @Cubic You see, it is never safe to do so, so the documentation remains correct—if unhelpful.

Comment: @cubic / others... feel free to post an answer!

Comment: And this is a good time to never forget rewrite rules, which can change a program drastically.  Look at the code _and_ the rewrite rules.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Modify calls `Data.Vector.Generic.modify` which calls `clone` which has the following rewrite rule:

```
"clone/new [Vector]" forall p.
  clone (new p) = p
```

So when something is in a syntactic form of `new p` it isn't copied.  It appears `modify`, `slice`, `init`, `tail`, `take`, `drop`, `unstream`, and `clone` are the main thing that fuse well here.  This is all closely related to the stream fusion work (google-able paper for deep dives) that underpins vector's design.

EDIT: Based on your comment I'll elaborate.  Only things syntactically in the form `new p` will avoid copying.  Since you're probably not writing `new` yourself then it will only appear as a result of inlined use of function from the vector package.  Looking at vector [1](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.0.1/docs/src/Data-Vector-Generic.html), it appears the functions I identified above use `new` and should thus allow `modify` to not copy *if things are inlined* and even then most those only preserve newness, the vector still had to be freshly constructed via something like `create`, `force`, `modify`, or `unstream`.

For example, if you have the code:

```
v = fromList [1..10]
g = modify f v
f = undefined
```

Then `v` will be inlined and the vector is in the form `new p` (because `fromList` uses `unstream` which is `new`) and therefore `modify` will not have to copy the array.

On the other hand, consider:

```
v = let v0 = fromList [1..10] in 
{-# NOINLINE v #-}
g = modify f v
```

Now `v` is not inlined explicitly - it could also not be inlined because it is from a different module or the expression is shared.  As a result there is no code that is *syntactically* `modify f (new p)` and the rewrite rule won't fire.

Less contrived, consider:

```
g = let v = fromList [1..10]
        t = v ! 4
        v2 = modify f v
    in t + (v2 ! 4)
```

This is a common pattern where a vector is both read and modified - it obviously can't be modified before the read and the rewrite rules either won't fire (because there is no `new` there) or you'll have to lose sharing of `v`.

[1](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.0.1/docs/src/Data-Vector-Generic.html) See [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.0.1/docs/src/Data-Vector-Generic.html) for the rules "slice/new [Vector]", for example.

Comment: Does this mean that for `modify` the vector is _never_ copied? Or are there still some cases for which it is?

Comment: I dare say in most cases it still is.