# Data.HashMap performances outside of IO

Tags: haskell, hashmap

I've discovered Helm (http://helm-engine.org/) the other day and I've been playing a bit with it. I like Elm, so Helm has been great to use thus far.
Simply put, the update function gets called every tick and get passed the model, and has to return an updated version of that model. Another function then gets called to render that model on screen.

For small games with not much in the model it seems ideal, but I've been thinking about something a bit bigger, for which a HashMap (or a lot of them) would be ideal, and I'm wondering about the performances of that.

I'm no expert but I believe using the Data.HashTable.IO should modify the hashtable in ram instead of creating a new copy on change, but that seems complicated to interface with Helm. That would mean using a Cmd for each lookups and each changes and returning that to Helmn and then get passed the result from a new call to update, a nightmare to use if you have more than one or two things to lookup I think.

Data.HashMap.Strict (or Lazy ?) would probably work better, but I imagine each change would create a new copy, and the GC would free up the old one at some future point. Is that correct ?
That would potentially mean hundreds of copy then free per frame, unless the whole thing is smart enough to realise I'm not using the old hashtable again after the change and just not copy it.

So how does this work in practice ? (I'm thinking of HashMap because it seems like the easier solution, but I guess this applies to regular lists too).

Comment: Don't prematurely optimize. If you can make the program you want with HashMaps, do it.

Comment: Well sure, but I'd rather not rewrite the whole thing in C after the fact because it's horribly slow, I'd rather know before if what I want to do will result in hundreds or thousands of pointless copies each frame or not

Comment: Then benchmark it to find out if it meets your requirements. Of find [someone else's benchmark](https://github.com/tanakh/hashtable-bench) and [use their results](https://rawgit.com/tanakh/hashtable-bench/master/result.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I support the comments about avoiding premature optimization and benchmarking, instead of guessing, to determine if performance is acceptable.  That said, you had some specific questions too.

> Data.HashMap.Strict (or Lazy ?) would probably work better, but I imagine each change would create a new copy, and the GC would free up the old one at some future point. Is that correct ?

Yes, the path to the modified node will consist of new nodes.  Modulo balancing, the sub trees on the left and right of the path will all be shared (not copied) by the old and new tree structures.

> That would potentially mean hundreds of copy then free per frame

I'm not sure where you get "hundreds" from.  Are you saying there are hundreds of updates?  For some structures there are rewrite rules that allow much of the intermediate values to be used in a mutating manner.  See for example, [this small examination of vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45840094/when-does-modify-copy-the-vector/45850410#45850410).

> So how does this work in practice ?

In practice people implement what they want and rework parts that are too slow.  I might reach for HashMap early, instead of assuming the containers `Data.Map` will suffice, but I don't go beyond that without evidence.

Comment: I'm going to change at least two values in each object in all the hashmaps every tick (the x and y coordinates), but if they can share everything that doesn't change, I guess it won't be that much work. That's what I wanted to know, thanks !